# How can I export TukeyHSD results into rows/columns when there's multiple factors

Tags: r, export, export-to-csv, anova, tukey

I'm trying to export my TukeyHSD results into a file. However, the only solutions I am able to find are when it's a simple comparison and not when I also want to consider another factor.

For example, this is the type of ANOVA I'm trying to do:

```
dat1 <- lm(Count~Treatment*Keio_gyrA, data=colony_counts2)
Anova(dat1)
```

In order to see these types of results (strain by treatment):

[image: img]

The only solution I have been able to find is:

```
mod1 <- aov(Count~Treatment*Keio_gyrA, data=colony_counts2)
tk1 <- TukeyHSD(mod1, 'Treatment', ordered = TRUE)
write.csv(as.data.frame(tk1$'Treatment:Keio_gyrA'), "colony counts ANOVA2.csv")
```

But no matter what I do, it'll either only give me `Count~Treatment`, `Count~Keio_gyrA`, or an error.

The above gave me the error:

> Error in TukeyHSD.aov(mod1, "Treatment", "Keio_gyrA", ordered = TRUE) : 'which' specified no factors"

But rearranging the statement and trying to include `Treatment` and `Keio_gyrA` in any way together doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried the `cat` function (code below) and while I am able to get a .txt file, it isn't in columns/rows so it's very difficult to pull information from.

```
dat3 <- lm(Max_OD~Treatment:Keio_gyrA, data=max_OD2)
Anova(dat3)
out3 <- capture.output(TukeyHSD(aov(dat3)))
cat(out3, file="ANOVA Max OD.txt", sep=" ", append=TRUE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to work with `tk1 <- TukeyHSD(mod1)`?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to have a report/write-up of your analyses, you may be better-off with a different strategy/work-flow, namely, [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html), which automatically writes text, code, and output to a file (e.g., html, doc, pdf).

Comment: @hplieninger ha, of course it'd be as simple as that.. thanks!